# Ajax If else not workign when i use GET

Tags: javascript, ajax

Here Is my Ajax function and JSON data. I want to print the value in 2 input fields. The first input field is updated but the second one is not.

```
<select name="products" required class="form-control changeStatus"id="major_type_selected" onchange="get_inventory_check_for_order_ajax(this)">
    <option value="None">--Select a Type--</option>
    <option value="1">123</option>
    <option value="2">456</option>                                 
</select>
<input class="form-control sub_type_data"  value="0" type="number" name="wh_qty"/> 
<input class="form-control sub_type_datas" id="sub_type_datas" value="0"  type="number" name="SL_qty"/>
```

This is the JSON data:

> "[{\"model\": \"inventory.productlocation\", \"pk\": 14, \"fields\":
>   {\"location\": \"IU\", \"quantity\": 0, \"product\": 5}}, {\"model\":
>   \"inventory.productlocation\", \"pk\": 13, \"fields\": {\"location\":
>   \"SL\", \"quantity\": 5, \"product\": 5}}, {\"model\":
>   \"inventory.productlocation\", \"pk\": 15, \"fields\": {\"location\":
>   \"WH\", \"quantity\": 6, \"product\": 5}}]"

This is the javascript code

```
function get_inventory_check_for_order_ajax(ref) {

            var thisIs = $(ref);
            products = thisIs.val();

            console.log(products);


            $.ajax({
                'url': "{% url 'get_inventory_check_for_order' %}",
                'type': "GET",
                'data': {"products":products},
                'async': false,
                'success': function (data) {
                    if (data == "empty") {
                        $('#sub_type_data').html("");
                        $('#sub_type_data').append($('<option/>').attr("value", "None").text("--Select Wharehouse--").prop('selected', true).prop('disabled', true));
                    } else {
                        results = JSON.parse(data)
                        $.each(results, function(index, result){
                            console.log(result.fields.location);
                            if (result.fields.location == 'WH'){
                     thisIs.parent().next().find(".sub_type_data").val(result.fields.quantity);

                            }
                            else if (result.fields.location == 'SL'){
                                # Here the second input field's value should change
                                thisIs.parent().next().find(".sub_type_datas").val(result.fields.quantity);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Could you please specify your question? I'm not sure what is your issue...

Comment: @valbuxvb my  else if (result.fields.location == 'SL'){
                                thisIs.parent().next().find(".sub_type_datas").val(result.fields.quantity);
                               } is not show data

Comment: I think it will be `find(".sub_type_data")` not `find(".sub_type_datas")` . There seems to be an extra s after data

Comment: @brk no buddy. not working

Comment: @brk if you see question there is two input field.

Comment: what happens if you console.log(result.fields.quantity) in that if statement?

Comment: @valbuxvb in console show exact value but not show input field.

Comment: Ok, since in your question the value of result.fields.location is equal to "WH", are you sure it gets into the desired if block? Because with the data you specified it will get in the first if block.

Comment: @valbuxvb yes you are right when else statement come then console show exact value. but i don't know why not show in input field value

Comment: Could you please add some more HTML? I think the problem could be that you're refering to the wrong element. But I cannot be sure until  I see from what element the function is called.

Comment: @valbuxvb edit question. check html code

Comment: @valbuxvb check now

Comment: I think the problem could be that ".next()". What happens if you remove it?

Comment: @valbuxb thisIs.parent().find(".sub_type_datasl").val(result.fields.quantity);
like this . nothing happend. zero value show

Comment: .sub_type_datasl?

Comment: sorry thisIs.parent().find(".sub_type_datas").val(result.fields.quantity);

Comment: typing mistake @valbuxvb

Comment: You see, since you are using an else if statement, it will never enter in that block, thus show anything in that input field, because of _if result.fields.location == 'WH'_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your required html is in the next element.

So : `thisIs.parent().next().next().find(ELEM).val(result.fields.quantity);`

Answer (score 0):

Use it without empty keyword

Use:

```
if (data){}  //this will run if "data" has some value otherwise else statement is encountered
```

Comment: my both statement have value.

Comment: If you have more then one statement and want to perform action on each, this can't be done by using if else.. You can use multiple if statements